# divide shapefile into equal sized grids

Tags: r, r-sf, r-sp, terra

I want to divide a shapefile into equal size grids (polygons). This is how I am doing it:

```
  # load shapefile 

  library(geodata)
  library(terra)
  
  can_shp <- geodata::gadm('CAN', level = 1, path = file.path(dir_ls$input, 'shapefile'))
  can_shp <- can_shp[can_shp$NAME_1 == 'British Columbia']
  
  # using the extent of the shapefile, create a raster 
  
  temp_raster <- terra::rast(xmin = ext(can_shp)[1], 
                             xmax = ext(can_shp)[2], 
                             ymin = ext(can_shp)[3], 
                             ymax = ext(can_shp)[4],
                             resolution = 0.008333333,
                             crs = crs(can_shp),
                             val = 0)

# retain only those raster cells that are within the boundary of the shapefile
  
  temp_raster <- terra::mask(temp_raster, can_shp)
  temp_raster <- terra::crop(temp_raster, can_shp)  
  
# convert the resulting raster into grid cells (polygons) 
  
  temp_grid <- as.polygons(temp_raster, trunc = FALSE, dissolve = FALSE)
```

`temp_grid` is what I am after which will give me equal grids within the countary boundary but the last step is taking hours and wondered if there's anything I am doing wrong here or if there's any faster way to do this.

Comment: I suspect your approach to subset `can_shp` isn't doing what you think it should, and your hours are involved in making polygon/cellsize=0.0083 for all of Canada.

Comment: st_bbox(can_shp$geometry[2])
      xmin       ymin       xmax       ymax 
-139.05220   48.30861 -114.05422   60.00007 # this is BC, what are your terra::rast ext(can_shp)[1] & etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your script in more concise form, and for a smaller country that does not need to be downloaded. It shows that your approach works, in principle.

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r <- terra::rast(v, resolution = 0.008333333, vals=1)
r <- terra::mask(r, v)
g <- as.polygons(r, dissolve=FALSE)
```

Doing the same for British Columbia creates a very large set of polygons that would be hard to manipulate. Keeping your data as a raster is much more efficient. So, to me, the question is why you want these polygons. You would almost certainly be better off without them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with the `sf` package, which allows easy grid creation and reduction of polygons to those within boundaries. Here's an example using the sample North Carolina data from the package itself. `ggplot2` just used for clearer visuals.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.1, PROJ 9.0.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggplot2)

# sample North Carolina data
nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"))
#> Reading layer `nc.gpkg' from data source 
#>   `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/sf/gpkg/nc.gpkg' using driver `GPKG'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27

plot(nc, max.plot = 1)
```

[image]

```r
# make grid from the extents
nc_grid <- st_make_grid(nc)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc, fill = "grey", color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = nc_grid, fill = NA) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

```r
# filter the grid to cells within NC
nc_filter <- st_within(nc_grid, st_union(nc)) %>% lengths > 0

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc, fill = "grey", color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = nc_grid[which(nc_filter)], fill = NA) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to demonstrate this for a cell size of 0.008333333 i.e. do `nc_grid <- st_make_grid(nc, cellsize = 0.008333333)`. My question was if there's any package/method that's much faster than `terra`.

Comment: I think, though likely wrong, that you don't arrive directly at cellsize =, rather you're fishing around for `n` that will approximate 0.0083 (which is relatively small), where n = c(10,10) as default in st_make_grid and needs adjusting to satisfy `cellsize = c(diff(st_bbox(x)[c(1, 3)]), diff(st_bbox(x)[c(2, 4)]))/n`.

Comment: You're right, this answer is incorrect as is not faster through testing.